# Distributing letters evenly on a label regardless off the size of the letters

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I am trying to write my first iOS program and I need to display a matrix of letters and move its vertical lines separately because this matrix of letters is larger than the screen itself.

I would like these letters to be evenly spaced both in horizontal and vertical directions regardless what the actual letter is. **i** and **y** have different widths and **o** and **b** have different heights. What I am looking for is to have a table and each letter occupies a single cell.

First, I choose UILabel to display the individual vertical lines, because this way I can animate the lines. However, with the labels the letters are not distributed evenly.

Is there a way to tell the individual letters in a UILabel to occupy x amount of width regardless of the width of an actual letter?

Is there a better control or view in iOS to construct a matrix of letters and still be able to move its vertical lines separately?

Answer (score 1):

Very quick answer: Use a fixed width font, like Courier, which spaces all letters equally.

Comment: Good suggestion. Not sure though how well it will go with the design-sensitive apple crowd, but we will give it a try :)

Comment: Mine's probably not the best solution, just the quickest. If you go with using a view for each letter, remember that Apple recommends less than 3 subviews per table view cell. Any more and the scrolling starts to get jerky. Check out the docs, especially "A Closer Look at Table-View Cells" for how to subclass UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

You should definetly think about a programmatic way. If you do this with interface-builder you do exactly what it is not meant for: Expensive point and click adventures!

Just create a UILabel within a specific size, create the next, next, next, next, and then you move to the next line. I hopefully don't have to explain to you how that works. And keep in mind, that you create them in loadView !!!! ^^

Comment: @weggingho, thanks for the answer. We creating this view in a porgrammatic way...

Answer (score 1):

- Create one UILabel for each letter
- Make all labels the same width and height
- Set [textAlignment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW15) to UITextAlignmentCenter
- Distribute them evenly in your grid

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we will give it a try. Do you know how creating couple of hundreed labels will affect the performance? Not sure if this will be an impact at all, but If you have any experience in this area would love to hear!

Comment: @gyurisc, I don't think it will be a problem. I haven't used that many labels, but filling the screen with tons of views is not a problem (unless you try to animate them or something). Try it!

Comment: Animation is unfortunately key in our case.

Comment: @gyurisc Animating hundreds of uiviews at the same time may be a performance problem. I suggest you make a simple test an try it for yourself. Shouldn't be that hard to verify if it will work or not.